# Change the "device name" in the details window of System settings

Tags: system-info, device-name

I would like to change my "Device name" as shown in the settings panel. How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: 1st answer worked fine for me on 14.04, many thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Execute the following command using a terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/present-host-name/new-host-name/' /etc/hosts
sudo sed -i 's/present-host-name/new-host-name/' /etc/hostname
```

You can check your **present-host-name** by `cat /etc/hostname` or `hostname`.

Then reboot the computer, to see the changes.

Comment: Only renaming the hostname change the device name in details. but There will be an error relating to hostname in each sudo command to terminal

Comment: Thats right. I rewrote the description.

Answer (score 10):

- Open a terminal and issue the command

  ```
  gksu gedit /etc/hosts
  ```
- Then change the line

  ```
  127.0.1.1   victor-System-Product-Name
  ```

  with

  ```
   127.0.1.1    your-desired-name
  ```
- Then also open the file `/etc/hostname` with command `gksu gedit /etc/hostname` and change the hostname there to reflect the new name.
- Then reboot the computer, to see the changes

Comment: Or `sudo hostname preferredname` ?

Comment: @Samik, unfortunately `sudo hostname preferredname` won't work. I checked that. thanks

Comment: Sorry, these steps don't work, but I guess it's good to change the etc/hosts file to reflect what is in etc/hostname anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @VictorS, yes, only changing the hostname causes errors to be shown in terminal

Answer (score 4):

You can use the built in service `hostnamectl`

```
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname [NEW-HOSTNAME]
```

replacing `[NEW-HOSTNAME]` with the hostname you would like
this should work immediately on most things but I would reboot for good measure.

Comment: very nice.. Changes are immediate..

Answer (score 2):

Since there are plenty of ways to get something done here is one more:

While in your root directory:

```
cd /etc
sudo vi hostname
```

Type in your admin password, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Press `i` to 'insert' and change existing device name to the desired device name.

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>  and type `:wq!`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Restart the system for the change to take affect.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command , it will open up Text editor

```
sudo gedit /etc/hostname
```

Replace the present name to your Desired name. Save and close. Reboot for it  to take effect.

Comment: Only changing the hostname, causes error to be shown on each sudo command to the terminal

Comment: Thanks for noticing me about that , can you post the exact errors  you see . According to [Hostname man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/hostname.1.html) **`Edit  /etc/hostname  for permanent change`**, even i tried this method and haven't encountered any such errors.

Comment: I edited `/etc/hostname` to a new name `anwar` from previous one `anwar-precise`. The error after rebooting the system and executing a sudo command is `sudo: unable to resolve host anwar`. It may be only warning. I executed `sudo gedit` command

Comment: I searched for these and concluded you need to change both `hosts` and `hostname` to reflect complete changes , depending on maybe loopback , DNS , domain-name, resolv.conf. But its better to do changes in both of them. Yet i haven't encountered any such `error` ,must be different interface.