# Change name in terminal to something shorter

Tags: command-line

So on every line in terminal, it leads with something like this:

```
bs7280@bs7280-Lenovo-IdeaPad-U530-Touch:~/path/to/dir$
```

is there a way to make this shorter, without all of the useless text out front? so maybe it looks something like this:

```
bs7280:~/path/to/dir$
```

Comment: You could set PS1=yourname@yourhost in .bashrc file in your homefolder

Answer (score 0):

You can change this by changing your hostname as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159558/change-the-device-name-in-the-details-window-of-system-settings).  The hostname is basically the name of your computer, so this will only have to be changed once to affect all users.